# Unable to set mongodb path in meteor on window system

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I googled for the whole day but did not found any solution to change default database in meteor for window system. All findings are as follows

```
MONGO_URL=mongodb://127.0.0.1:27018/meteor  meteor
```

Gives error on window system -

> 'MONGO_URL' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

Used settings.json as

```
{
    "MONGO_URL":"mongodb://127.0.0.1:27018/meteor"
}
```

and then meteor `--settings ./settings.json`

but still it does not pick this mongo setting. Finally in my js file

```
if (Meteor.isServer){     
    process.env.MONGO_URL="mongodb://127.0.0.1:27018/meteor"
}
```

This also not working. Any suggestion in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Have you seen this: https://github.com/meteor/windows-preview/issues/52

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If I am not mistaken Meteor settings are used only for deployment.

To use another MongoDB than the local one on windows during development, you can create a batch file (*.bat) containing the following commands in your Meteor app folder:

```
SET MONGO_URL=mongodb://localhost:27017/name_of_the_db
meteor
```

(Considering that your MongoDB server is listening on localhost:27017 which are the default settings)

Comment: Does meteor spin up the mongo server as well, or does it need to be running already? If meteor takes care of that, is there a way to provide the `dbpath` as an argument to meteor?