# MongoError: invalid operator '$split'

Tags: mongodb, meteor, aggregation-framework

Im doing an aggregation in Meteor. What I want to do is to make a list which for every word that appears in the titles of the articles and make an array that contains all the articles that have that word in its title. When I test it, i get `MongoError: invalid operator '$split'`

Here is the code:

```
Meteor.publish("topics", function () {
  // Remember, ReactiveAggregate doesn't return anything
  ReactiveAggregate(this, Articles, [
    {
      $project: {
              topic: { $split: ["$title", " "] }
      }
    },
    {
      $unwind: {
              path: "$topic"
      }
    },
    {
      $group: {
              _id: "$topic",
              articles: { $push: "$$ROOT" }
      }
    }
  ], { clientCollection: "clientTopic" });
});
```

Comment: What version of mongodb are you running?

Comment: To be more direct [`$split`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/split/) is only introduced in MongoDB 3.4. If you are using a "default" meteor installation, then you have MongoDB 3.2 at best, and therefore the operator is not supported. If you want to use "newest features" then instead install a standalone MongoDB instance, and follow the instructions to ["Connect Meteor to External MongoDB"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38713003/how-to-connect-to-external-mongodb-instance-in-meteor)

Comment: @BurhanKhalid Split is in mongo 3.4 and i'm running mongo 3.2.12. I read that meteor uses mongo up to version 3.2. What can i do in order to make that aggregation if I can't use split?

Comment: @NeilLunn Yes you are right. Do you know how can I get similar results with this version of mongo?

Comment: You either install a standalone MongoDB as instructed or use mapReduce instead

Comment: But more to the point "Install the latest version". When you deploy your meteor app you will be using a separate server instance anyway. This "should" be MongoDB 3.4. MongoDB 3.6 is getting near release candidate stage, so it's not like 3.4 is "hot off the press". So you "should" be using it.

Comment: Of course the **other alternative** is clearly *"Do not store a space delimited string in your data in the first place"*. The `$split` or `.split()` functions are merely "coercing" this form of "string" into an "Array". So instead, *"Just store the data as an array"* and you then do not need `$split` or `.split()` to process. Simple.

Comment: @NeilLunn Thanks for your help! I think I'll try to update mongo; but if I have troubles will go for the second option and store it like an array.