# insert data to external mongodb with meteor app

Tags: mongodb, meteor, insert, external

I have an instant of mongodb in the server , ana i connect my meteor app to this DB using that code :  **lib/connection.js**

```
 MONGO_URL = 'mongodb://xxxxxxxx';
   var mongoClient = require("mongodb").MongoClient;
   mongoClient.connect(MONGO_URL, function (err, db) {

    if (err) {
            console.log('Unable to connect to the mongoDB server. Error:', err);
        } else {
            console.log('Connection established to cc', MONGO_URL);


             var collection = db.collection('test');
             var test1= {'hello':'test1'};
             collection.insert(test1);      
             db.close();
       }

    });
```

the connextion to the the external mongo is established and the collection test is created in the server but my app still connected to the the local mongo when i insert my collection: books:

**thee code :  collections/Books.js**

```
Books= new Mongo.Collection('books');

BooksSchema= new SimpleSchema({

  name: {
    type: String,
    label: "Name"
    autoform:{
     label: false,
      placeholder: "schemaLabel"
        }
  },
  categorie:{
    type: String,
    label: "Categorie"
    autoform:{
     label: false,
      placeholder: "schemaLabel"
        }
  },


});

Meteor.methods({
deleteBook: function(id) {
  Cultures.remove(id);
}

});

Books.attachSchema(BooksSchema);
```

**code client/books.html**

```
 <template name="books">
    <p>add new books </p>
    {{> quickForm collection="Books" id="newBook" type="insert" class="nform" buttonContent='ajouter' buttonClasses='btn bg-orange'}}
    </template>
```

help bleaaaaaz

Comment: how can i modifie my code to make the data inserted into the external DB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should specify the database that is supposed to be used in `MONGO_URL` environment variable, not in your code. If you work locally start your application like this:

```
MONGO_URL="mongodb://xxxxxxxx" meteor
```

**UPD**

Don't know about Windows. See this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29824944/unable-to-set-mongodb-path-in-meteor-on-window-system).

Looks like you should set env vars in windows like this:

```
set MONGO_URL=mongodb://localhost:27017/mydbname
```

Comment: thnk you for uor answer, i tried that but i work in windows , the MOGO_URL dosnt work , i treid to make that code in server/main.js       ****************        Meteor.startup(() => {
 console.log(process.env.MONGO_URL);
process.env['MONGO_URL'] = 'mongodb://xxxxxxxx';
console.log(process.env.MONGO_URL);
});**************

Comment: witch means that the environment variable is modified but the data still inserted in the local mongodb

Answer (score 0):

ok thnk you Ramil , i create a new system environment variable on windows , MOGO_URL with value equal : mongodb://xxxxxxxx, and it works; the application is connected to the database in the server , and the data is inserted into it .
now my problem is how to get the data from that DB , I user Microsoft azure to stock the db with API DocumentDB

Comment: I guess it's the matter of another question since you solved your problem with connection. Good luck!